# SQL selecting one column multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server

so I have two tables:

```
create table teams(
teamShortName varchar(3) not null,
teamLongName varchar(35) not null,
PRIMARY KEY(teamShortName)
)

create table results(
matchID int identity(1,1)
homeTeam varchar(3) not null references teams(teamShortName),
awayTeam varchar(3) not null references teams(teamShortName),
homeTeamGoals int not null,
awayTeamGoals int not null,
PRIMARY KEY(matchID)
)
```

Now I want to create view/select that would give me results but with teamLongNames...

Tried some stuff, but with no succes - getting same names for home and away team / null values for both sides

data would look like this

```
teamShortName     teamLongName
     RMD         FC Real Madrid
     FCB         FC Barcelona

matchID     homeTeam   awayTeam   homeTeamGoals   awayTeamGoals
   1           RMD        FCB           2               2
```

result would look like this

```
    Home        HomeGoals        AwayGoals        Away
FC Real Madrid      2                2         FC Barcelona
```

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Provide some sample data, and the expected result

Comment: Please tag the DBMS you use (database).

Comment: added both as u asked for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use alias and you can link table twice

```
SELECT HT.teamLongName, homeTeamGoals, aT.teamLongName, awayTeamGoals
FROM results INNER JOIN teams HT on  homeTeam = HT.teamShortName
INNER JOIN teams AT ON awayTeam = AT.teamShortName
```

Comment: Outer joins? You expect matches played by one or even zero teams? Weird.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Changed to inner join..Thanks for pointing out

Comment: @Michal Janošec Can you please show screenshot for data in table?

Comment: @AswaniMadhavan edited my post, got the result with your help, thanks... I would post it, but I have the DB in my (czech) language, think it would not help anybody :D

Comment: @Michal Janošec posted that for your previous comment.No need to post as your issue is resolved

Comment: @AswaniMadhavan sure, one more time, thank you, took me long time to get aliases purpose :)

Comment: @Michal Janošec :)